# Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function on indexOf

Tags: javascript, get, typeerror, indexof, location-href

I currently have this code to check the website URL GET options for a specific ID, but whenever this code is run, I get a weird error: `Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var familyid = "id=8978566";
    var corporateid = "id=8978565";

    if(window.location.indexOf(familyid) === -1)
       {
        document.write("Family ID not found");
       }

</script>
```

It would be awesome if i could get some guidance on this issue... I couldn't find similar issues using the `.indexOf()` function

Answer (score 21, accepted):

window.location is a [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object, not a string, and `indexOf` is a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (or [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)) method.

If you want to search the query params, try

```
window.location.search.indexOf(familyId)
```

or if you want check the whole url,

```
window.location.toString().indexOf(familyId)
```

Comment: You could try calling a toString. Making that one line:  if(window.location.toString().indexOf(familyid) === -1)